# Prestashop link employees to Customer Groups

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am looking for a way to link Customer Groups to Employees.

My Customers are assigned to Groups and those groups can only see certain product categories. Which means my customers can only see certain products depending on which category they are assigned to.

Now when an employee creates an order for a customer, they can pick any product that they want when the "search products" in the order form.  My product categories fail and it creates lots of problems for my business.

So i want my employees to be assigned to the customer groups.  What i did is a added a column in my ps_employee called "id_default_group" (same column name as the one in the ps_customer) and i added the appropriate IDs.

My question is what do i have to do in the php files to look for this column?

PrestaShop version 1.6.1.6

Comment: This can be achieved with a module and no database modifications with two hooks `actionAdminAddProductOnOrderBefore` and `actionAdminUpdateQtyBefore` which trigger before a product is added into a cart or order from backoffice. Inside them you can validate if a product belongs to a category that a customer has access to.

Comment: sorry i am not sure what to do.  how do i modify those two hooks? can you please give me an example?  thank you!